# Why the value of Gaussian curve drop to 1/19 at 2 standard deviation?

Tags: gaussian, probability-distribution-function

Taken from [Guide to DSP](https://www.dspguide.com/ch2/5.htm) where it says:

> ... at two ... standard deviations from the mean, the value of the
> Gaussian curve has dropped to about 1/19 ...

It seems to be a straight forward calculation but my math just didn't work out to 1/19. The Gaussian probability distribution function is given by:

$$ P(x) = {1 \over \sqrt{2\pi} \sigma } e^{-{{(x - \mu)^2} \over {2 \sigma^2}}} $$

At the mean (where maximum probability occurs),

$$ \begin{align} P(\mu) &= {1 \over \sqrt{2\pi} \sigma } e^{-{{(\mu - \mu)^2} \over {2 \sigma^2}}} \\ &= {1 \over \sqrt{2\pi} \sigma } e^{0} = {1 \over \sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} \end{align} $$

And at 2 standard deviation, or $ x = \mu +2\sigma $

$$ \begin{align} P(\mu + 2\sigma) &= {1 \over \sqrt{2\pi} \sigma } e^{-{{(\mu + 2\sigma - \mu)^2} \over {2 \sigma^2}}} \\ &= {1 \over \sqrt{2\pi} \sigma } e^{-{{4\sigma^2} \over {2 \sigma^2}}} = {1 \over \sqrt{2\pi} \sigma } e^{-2} \end{align} $$

To see how much probability has dropped from max probability at $ \mu $ to probability at $ 2\sigma $, I can simply take the ratio:

$$ { P(\mu + 2 \sigma) \over P(\mu) } = { {{1 \over {\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}} e^{-2}} \over {{1 \over {\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}}}} = e^{-2} = 0.135 \approx {2 \over 15} \neq {1 \over 19} $$

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a mistake. Since he publishes errata as well, maybe drop the author an email.

Comment: The blog must have referred to the standard normal distribution, i.e. the Gaussian curve with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$. In that case, the values of the PDF at 2, 4, and 6 are 1/19, 1/7563, and 1/166,666,666 respectively. I agree that the wording of the blog is confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've computed the most general case and have shown it's always 2/15, thus 1/19 is incorrect, at least if interpreting "1/x-th of value" as $f(\text{value})/f_\text{max}$. [This simulation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/naiezibbqz) confirms it.

**Edit**:  I took a guess, 1/19 is the *value of the Gaussian* at two standard deviations for $(\mu, \sigma) = (0, 1)$, which does qualify per exact wording of "the value drops to 1/19". But I agree your measure is more meaningful as it's independent of $(\mu, \sigma)$ and interprets as "the value drops to 2/15 of its peak value".

Answer (score 3):

As noted by AlexTP and OverLordGoldDragon, the confusion is that the actual value of the Gaussian probability density curve is 1/19, while the value compared to the 0.4 peak value is 2/15.

When talking about probability distributions, the middle or peak value does not have a particular significance. **The absolute value of PDF is more useful in practice than the ratio to peak value.**

For example, a distribution that has a wide flat peak with sharp edges would have a lower peak probability, for example 0.2. If it has density of 1/19 at 2 sigma, it has the same probability of having outliers that far as the Gaussian distribution would. But if you used the comparison to peak value, you would think it was less sharp drop than the Gaussian, just because the middle is more flat.

---

As an example, let's compare the [Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) to [Gaussian (normal) distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution):

[image: Distribution comparison]
<sup>([Image source](https://www.vosesoftware.com/riskwiki/Laplacedistribution.php))</sup>

The ratio of value at 2 standard deviations compared to peak value is 0.1 for both distributions. The actual probability of events outside 2 sigma is lower for Gaussian distribution, while Laplace distribution does have steeper descent at the middle.

The discussion in the original article was that in Gaussian distribution the "tails drop toward zero very rapidly", where tails means the long portion further away from middle.

Comment: Valid observation, but in context the author seeks to illustrate the fast rate of decay of the Gaussian; this requires a referential measure, which absolute values don't provide. (Granted, providing _multiple_ absolute values also does the trick in this case)

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Because PDFs always have an integral of 1, absolute values are comparable.

Comment: 1/19 by itself provides no information on extent of decay, whereas 2/15 does. Only if another absolute value is provided can one infer about rate of decay.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Yeah, I guess it depends on viewpoint. I expanded the answer a bit to better explain what I mean.

Comment: Please note that if the purpose is to characterize how likely are the extremes, we use the CDF and, therefore, the ratio mean/tail has no significant meaning. Another point is that a distribution is employed in practice because it suits real-world datasets, not because of the nice properties of the distribution. In particular, the Gaussian distribution is widely used just because of the central limit theorem that allows *approximating* many practical kinds of stuff by the aforementioned distribution.

Comment: +1, good comparison

Comment: @AlexTP The ratio remains useful: it quantifies the rate of change of probability with respect to the dependent variable. That is, an event becomes much less likely due to a nudge in the variable under some distributions than others. (Though it's more an illustrative surrogate for the actual measure that's the derivative, so not the best)

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon As PDF and CDF are equivalent if they both exist, you can see what you want to see. Nonetheless, in practice, we don't use such property to characterize the likelihood of an event. Check literature.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Also, what about a uniform distribution whose support is $[-M\sigma,+M\sigma]$ where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the normal distribution of interest. The ratio "mean to (every point of the support)" is $1$, and I can choose $M$ to make the PDF value as small as I want. The ratio is not useful without assuming a class of distribution.

Comment: @AlexTP It's not universal. One use is analyzing energy localization of wavelet transforms under probabilistic resolution measures; the decay ratio quantifies strength of neighbor contribution to correlation. The ratio has uses if function shape is of interest (and is preferably unimodal), and OP's linked context explicitly concerns with rate of decay.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon (1) No, the OP's linked context wants to justify "In practice, the sharp drop of the Gaussian pdf dictates that these extremes almost never occur." by the rate of decay, which is confusing and simply misleading. In the context of the OP's question and the referenced blog, the ratio is only useful to compare two normal distributions. (2) I don't say that the ratio is always useless because if you want to use it, it is useful. But, again, not in the context of this specific question of the OP.

Comment: @AlexTP Agreed decay isn't a good general likelyhood indicator. The blog means to provide intuition on Gaussian's quick decay (which, for a function without inflections, necessarily implies quick CDF decay); putting aside whether it's a good idea, I state that _for that purpose_, the ratio to peak measure is more meaningful, as individual values are informative, and convey that the Gaussian's standard deviation is invariant to affine transformation (stretching / shifting).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I don't see any ambiguity in the sentence I quoted that quick decay is not the focus of the blog, and I don't change my opinion that the blog is technically wrong. Assuming that for the purpose of showing a quick decay, yes you can use the ratio. For your last statement, sorry, I don't see why we need the ratio to tell the standard deviation is invariant to affine transformation.

Comment: @AlexTP Absolute value at $s$ standard deviations changes, but not ratio to peak; since this holds at all points and for every $(\mu, \sigma)$, it illustrates invariance.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Affine transformation is not my expertise, and this is out of the topic of the OP's question. Nonetheless, as it seems that you are interested, I have two questions. (1) does your statement hold for ALL distributions or only for some distributions, in particular the normal distributions?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon and  (2) Isn't the invariance just a consequence of "the affine transformation of a normally distributed random variable is a normally distributed random variable"? For (2), to avoid writing down rigorous proof, just think that distribution is fully defined by its PDF. I mean *your statement about the invariance may be a nice property, but not many find it useful, sorry*. You may want to create a new question or answer to avoid extending this comment section.

Comment: @AlexTP To be clear, my motivation solely pertains to descriptions of a function's shape, nothing to do with probability. I don't claim the ratio is a sound description for any general PDF - rather, for illustrating decay, it's more meaningful than absolute values. For _some_ PDF, this happens to provide useful characterization. -- (2): sure. I meant, the fact that this ratio stays constant is good for intuitive illustration (which the entire DSP guide strives for). -- If you have more comments we can continue under my answer, but basically, I don't disagree much with you on probability stuff.